# Ошибка в классе наследования...

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

class Cat {  
public:  
    void GetName();  
};

class Dog: public Cat {  
public:  
    void GetName();  
};

void Cat::GetName() {  
    cout << "name\n";  
}

int main() {  
    Dog MyDog;  
    MyDog.GetName();  
    return 0;  
}
```

Ошибки:

> `ExConstr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Dog::GetName(void)" (?GetName@Dog@@QAEXXZ)
> Debug/ExConstr.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals  
> Error executing link.exe.`
>
> `ExConstr.exe - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)`

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: C Builder или Visual?

Comment: Visual... Не пойму, что происходит...

Comment: прикольно, класс котопес

Comment: собаки произошли от кошек? круто!

Comment: Да какя разница, кто от кого произошел?! Это голый пример.

Comment: а еще можно пример 

class human: public ape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Линковщик не может найти реализацию `Dog::GetName(void)`.

Добавьте в код

```
void Dog::GetName() {  
    cout << "name\n";
}
```

Comment: Это же смешно! Какой тогда смысл от наследования, если я заново пишу функции-члены, которые хочу унаследовать? Бред!

Comment: В этом случае нужно использовать виртуальные функции и работу через указатели. Получите то, что хотите.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

class Cat {  
public:  
    void GetName();

};

class Dog: public Cat {

};

void Cat::GetName() {  
    cout << "Cat name\n";
}

int main() {  
    Dog MyDog;  
    MyDog.GetName();  // Cat name
    //system("pause");
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Пес не унаследовал функцию GetName() от Кота, потому что Вы ее переопределили в классе Пес. Теперь она совершенно самостоятельная, песья, а не унаследованная. При этом еще и не написали реализацию. Удалите объявление GetName() у Пса, и все будет в порядке. Если все же хотите написать для Пса что-то свое, то объявите кошачью GetName() виртуальной.

Comment: То есть наследованные методы не объявляются в классе наследника, я правильно понял?

Comment: Почти. Если Вы хотите, чтобы собака имела свою собственную реализацию GetName(), и, при этом, она бы все-таки наследовалась от Кота, то у Кота
она должна быть virtual void GetName(). Тогда можно ее объявлять у Пса и писать свою реализацию. А использовать ее можно будет в том числе и через указатель на базовый класс.

http://hashcode.ru/questions/49735/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC

Comment: Т.е. если вы у собаки, которая прикинулась котом, спросите имя, то она скажет своё собачье имя. (В случае двух методов, без virtual, она в собачьем обличьи говорит собачье имя, а в кошачьем -- кошачье)

Answer (score 2):

А что Вы хотите? Вы объявляете метод, но не описываете. Нельзя ли словами написать, что Вы хотите?
Вы можете добавить описание Dog::GetName, как советует [@fogbit](/users/2654/fogbit). У класса Cat будет свой метод GetName, а у Dog -- свой. Вы можете убрать описание `public void Dog::GetName();` из описания класса Dog, и тогда будет вызван метод родителя Cat::GetName() (кстати, когда это собаки рождались от кошек?).

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался!

Comment: Я тут неправильно выразился. В случае добавления у Вас будут два метода GetName (собачий и кошачий, и оба доступны для собак)